# How to actually check for model proven optimality with Potassco clingo python API?

Tags: python, answer-set-programming, clingo

I have the following code:

```
from clingo import Control

def on_model(m):
    print(m, m.optimality_proven)

ctl = Control(["0"])
ctl.add("base", (), "0 { a } 1. :~ a. [-1@0]")
ctl.ground([("base", ())])
solution = ctl.solve(on_model=on_model)
assert solution.exhausted
```

When I run it, the output is:

```
 False
a False
```

I am confused about why the `optimality_proven` flag is set to `False` in the second case. Clingo first checks the empty model, which is suboptimal, then it checks the model containing the single atom `a`, which is optimal. But for some reason it does not know it's optimal, even though the search is exhausted? Is that because the exhaustion only happens after this model is checked? But then, how do I get this flag to ever be se to `True`? I mean, I could do some workarounds like storing and comparing the generated models inside the `on_model` function to check for optimality myself, but that feels very unnatural, considering the API hints at the functionality already being available with this `optimality_proven` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you need to instantiate clingo control as follows:

```
ctl = Control(["0", "--opt-mode=optN"])
```

In this case, it will 'enumerate' optimal models after finding one with the m.optimality_proven flag set:

```
  False

a False

a True
```

Clingo outputs model once it finds them, so it probably doesn't know that the model is optimal when it outputs the second line. It is only known after it  exhausts the search.